# when clicking on create new hole Would like to be able to select a courseId

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a golf score app. I have created the database that has the following tables Round, Course and Hole.

The hole table has a foreign key to the courseId as when I create each hole I want to link it to a course.

When clicking on the create new I would like to have a dropdown list to select the courseId from when inputting all the hole details.

But when I click on the create new I get the following error in the Hole view model.

System.ArguementNullException: Value can not be Null. Parameter name items. in my Create action code within the HoleViewModelController.

This is my HoleViewModel code

```
    public class HoleViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int HoleId { get; set; }

    public int HoleNumber { get; set; }

    public int Par { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public int StrokeIndex { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int? CourseId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CourseNamesDropdownList { get; set; }

    public virtual CourseViewModel Course { get; set; }
}
```

}

This is my CourseViewModel code

```
    public class CourseViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public string CourseName { get; set; }
```

This is my HoleViewModelController Create action

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.CourseViewModels, "CourseId", "CourseName");
        return View();
    }
```

This is my MVC Create view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>HoleViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoleNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoleNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoleNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Par, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Par, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Par, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Length, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StrokeIndex, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StrokeIndex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StrokeIndex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseId, "CourseId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Course.CourseId, Model.CourseNamesDropdownList, "Please select from List", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would appear that `db.CourseViewModels` is null.

Comment: I can see that the error states that the db.CourseViewModel is null however the database has a value in so do not understand why it is saying it is null or how I get the values to show. When creating holes there will be the option to assign it to a number of different courses.

Comment: Where did you instantiate `db`?

Comment: At the top of HoleViewController I have the following code                                   
private MyGolfScoreAppDb db = new MyGolfScoreAppDb();

Comment: Ok that's a bit weird. I'm not sure what that's about then, tbh. Maybe someone with more EF experience will help with that.

Comment: But just to point out, once you sort that out, you still won't get anything displaying in your dropdown. `ViewBag.CourseId` is never used anywhere in your view. However in your `@Html.DropDownListFor` you've told it to to get the list of items from `Model.CourseNamesDropdownList`, which you aren't ever populating. You seem  a bit confused about how you want to store the items for the dropdown - in the viewbag, or in the model? You need to make your mind up about that, and about whether you're going to use a `SelectList` or a `List<SelectListItem>` (either is fine, but please choose!).

Comment: Your comment about choosing which to use has helped me solve the issue. I needed to add the following code arround the db.course and then create the selectlist. I also removed the viewbag message.

Comment: if you solved it that's great - but please add your code and explanation as a proper Answer below - then others in a similar situation who find it useful in future can upvote you :-). (They can't do that if you bury it in the comments - and also, questions with accepted answers rank higher in search results.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i resolved this issue by ammending the ActionResult Create code from

```
        public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.CourseViewModels, "CourseId", "CourseName");
    return View();
}
```

To

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var dbcourse = db.Course.ToList();

        //Make selectlist, which is IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
        var courseNameDropdownList = new SelectList(db.Course.Select(item => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = item.CourseName.ToString(),
            Value = item.CourseId.ToString()
        }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        // Assign the Selectlist to the View Model   
        var viewCourse = new HoleViewModel()
        {
            Course = dbcourse.FirstOrDefault(),
            // The Dropdownlist values
            CourseNamesDropdownList = courseNameDropdownList,

        };

        //ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.CourseViewModels, "CourseId", "CourseName");
        return View(viewCourse);
    }
```

This has allowed the dropdown to be populated and be added to the view.